# Amazon SES 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid

Tags: amazon-ses

In the code below I tried 2 combinations

1. The User (refer to attached image), the password
2. The Access ID and the Access Key

Both gave the same error. I ran this code in my eclipse environment in my home network.

**Error**

```
Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...
The email was not sent.
Error message: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid
```

[image: Amazon SES Users]

**Code**

```
public class amazon_ses_smtp_test {

    static final String FROM = "someone@myemail.com";   // This has been verified on the Amazon SES setup
    static final String TO = "justanyone@anydomain";  // I have production access

    static final String BODY = "This email was sent through the Amazon SES SMTP interface by using Java.";
    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "tried username and tried accesskey here";
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "tried the password and the access key"; 

    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";    

    static final int PORT = 25;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/plain");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...");

            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            transport.close();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can use 25 port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon SES 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid trying to rotate access key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653939/amazon-ses-535-authentication-credentials-invalid-trying-to-rotate-access-key)

Comment: I've tried all the answers here an so far nothing has worked for me

Comment: Check the AWS documentation, they change things drastically without bothering about the developers.

Comment: Also what have you tried is not clear.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my issue. I needed to specify the MIME version and content type as headers in the email and use port 587, since I am sending HTML templated emails. Also I found that I did not need to url encoded the SES SMTP username and password. In fact if I did, authentication failed for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **Important**
>
> Your SMTP user name and password are not the same as your AWS access key ID and secret access key. Do not attempt to use your AWS credentials to authenticate yourself against the SMTP endpoint. For more information about credentials, see Using Credentials With Amazon SES.

Here's the link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Comment: Those having this issue after rotating credentials for existing IAM user, you need to generate a new user from SES Dashboard. As mentioned in last comment here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=314976.

Answer (score 19):

The issue is fixed in our case with the following : The AWS SMTP had special characters in its credentials . The credentials have to be url encoded and then provided in the configuration.

Comment: Had the same issue. when using MAILER_URL password has to be url encoded

Comment: Oh my god I had the same issue. Thank you both or I wouldn't have spotted that. The password AWS SES generated was A-z 0-9 but it also had a / at the end of it (UGH) because 4 years later it turns out it is still badly designed. Escaping it as %2F fixed it for my use case.

Comment: Encoded to? what format. Stuck with this but also uncertain which is the username to use

Comment: Same issue here - ensure that the secret key does not contain any special characters such as %, /, +.

Comment: This was helpful for me too.
You can perform a urlencode by running the simple Python script:
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote_plus("BLx/n")

Comment: @user19 do i have to decode it before using it in config?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Terraform, you can use the following `.tf` file so that you can get the proper data

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "smtp_user" {
  name = "smtp_user"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "smtp_user" {
  user = aws_iam_user.smtp_user.name
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_sender" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["ses:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ses_sender" {
  name        = "ses_sender"
  description = "Allows sending of e-mails via Simple Email Service"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ses_sender.json
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.smtp_user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ses_sender.arn
}

output "smtp_username" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.smtp_user.id
}

output "smtp_password" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.smtp_user.ses_smtp_password_v4
}
```

This will output the user name and password needed for SMTP authentication for the region.

This will do the proper computation for the password.

Comment: Tried this an it seems right but is still not working for me. Is there a way to specify the region for this tf module?

Comment: you set it up on your provider I think.

Comment: I figured out my issue. I needed to specify the MIME version and content type as headers in the email and use port 587, since I am sending HTML templated emails. This Terraform module works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

I found that it's not enough to create the SES SMTP credentials. After you do that, go to Domains, select your domain, Identity Policies, Policy Generator. You'll need to get the SMTP user's ARN, which you can find in the IAM section.

Answer (score 7):

The smtp password is not the same as the secret access key. The smtp password can be obtained from your access key as described here on AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html#smtp-credentials-convert

Comment: Very rare that someone will use same for both. But a useful answer for sure.

Comment: @Siddharth I know, I found that weird as well. but check the link I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Obtaining Your Amazon SES SMTP Credentials

You need an Amazon SES SMTP user name and password to access the Amazon SES SMTP interface. You can use the same set of SMTP credentials in all AWS regions.

> Important

Your SMTP user name and password are different from your AWS access key ID and secret access key. For more information about credentials, see Using Credentials With Amazon SES.

**Follow this doc to get SMTP credentials**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html