# How can I use Amazon SES with Ghost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, ghost-blog

I saw at https://ghost.org/docs/config/#mail that SES is allowed.

But I edited my `config.production.json` and ran `ghost restart`, but Ghost still says:

> Set up Mailgun to start sending newsletters!

[image: screenshot]

The config I used was:

```
"mail": {
    "from": "My Name <example@example.com>",
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "options": {
      "host": "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "port": 465,
      "service": "SES",
      "auth": {
        "user": "asdfadsffdsf",
        "pass": "asdfasdfadfs"
      }
    }
  },
```

I got the SMTP-ACCESS-KEY-ID and SES-SMTP-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY from https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#/smtp

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I will try https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829419/470749 next.

Comment: did you managed to get any solution for this?

I am also having same issue with SES. Ghost is not printing any helpful lines in logs.

I am getting `cant send the magic link` on the UI when I am trying to subscribe.

Comment: I tried this as well.. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-rotate-smtp-access-keys/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue.

I fixed it by using the below config for Ghost.

```
"mail": {
      "transport": "SMTP",
      "options": {
          "host": "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          "port": 2465,
          "secure": true,
          "service": "SES",
          "from": "'Name' email",
          "auth": {
              "user": "access-key",
              "pass": "secret-access-key"
          }
      }
  }
```

Notice some changes from your config:

- `"port": 2465,`
- added `"secure": true,`
- use the IAM secret access key as it is. (Don't convert to SMTP password.)

Comment: Cool. Where did you learn that you needed to make those changes, such as the port number? I'm not using Ghost anymore, but I'll assume this answer is correct and accept it.

Comment: - Ports are given on SES console SMTP config. I just tried each port and succeed on the last one. :)

- for the secure true, SES requires SSL enabled requests, and Ghost docs had this parameter to enable SSL