# aws SES 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, smtp

I am trying to send message from java using **aws SES** .I saw similar question but I tried all the answers from that.
Question link: [Amazon SES 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452278/amazon-ses-535-authentication-credentials-invalid)

I have domain in **SES** management and created there from **SMTP** setting new *IAM* user with **SMTP** credentials, tried to login but giving this Error message: `535 Authentication Credentials Invalid`.

Here is code:

```
    static final String FROM = "news@example";  //have verified email
    static final String FROMNAME = "NAME";

    // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
    // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
    static final String TO = "my@gmail.com";

    // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "AKIAQZG5ZQZURE****";

    // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "MNYYlLz5sBB%2FA8****";//even encoded 

    // The name of the Configuration Set to use for this message.
    // If you comment out or remove this variable, you will also need to
    // comment out or remove the header below.
//    static final String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

    // Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the US West (Oregon) region.
    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints
    // for more information.
    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";

    // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint.
    static final int PORT = 25;

    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

    static final String BODY = String.join(
            System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "<h1>Amazon SES SMTP Email Test</h1>",
            "<p>This email was sent with Amazon SES using the ",
            "<a href='https://github.com/javaee/javamail'>Javamail Package</a>",
            " for <a href='https://www.java.com'>Java</a>."
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information.
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM,FROMNAME));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/html");

        // Add a configuration set header. Comment or delete the
        // next line if you are not using a configuration set
//        msg.setHeader("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Sending...");

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();
        }
    }
```

**Attached two pictures , first one is IAM permission policy and second is SES domain permission policy**

[image: IAM permission policy]

[image: SES domain permission policy]