Symfony 7 - Send Emails using AWS SES
I'm trying to sent emails with Symfony 7 using AWS. I installed symfony/amazon-mailer and updated my .env by adding this line:
MAILER_DSN=ses+smtp://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@default?region=eu-west-1

I, of course, replaced ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY with the proper values. When I test with php bin/console mailer:test myemail@email.com, I get the following error:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "AKIAZ5NA3C7CHL7O5R4B" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Authentication Credentials Invalid".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Authentication Credentials Invalid".".

I also tried with MAILER_DSN like this:
MAILER_DSN=ses://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@default?region=eu-west-1

But get this error:
Unable to send an email: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: from@example.org (code MessageRejected).

How do I send emails in Symfony with AWS SES? I don't have these issues in Node.js.

Did you check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452278/amazon-ses-535-authentication-credentials-invalid

@DmitryLeiko Ok. Now I can send an email using php bin/console mailer:test but it doesn't work from within the app. For example I don't get any email after I register
